# Unsafe attempt to load URL Nodejs res.send

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, xls

I am trying to send `xml` via NodeJs. My code is

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
res.send(body);
```

But chrome says

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL http://localhost:3030/my-file.xml from frame with URL http://localhost:3030/my-file.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `my-file.xsl` is that a typo?

Comment: @beautifulcoder Sorry, you are right. I did not get it first.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work is due to a security concern that Chrome has blocked XML files from accessing local files in the same directory, while HTML files can access.

Workaround:
On Windows: from the command prompt run

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

(replacing USERNAME with your username)

On Ubuntu:
for chromium browser type

```
chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files
```

for google chrome

```
google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Maybe you have to kill all running windows processes for chrome.exe in the windows task manager.